# How to create a mirror of a clearnet website?

Tags: onion-routing, mirrors

I have an already running https website and I would like to also have a full functioning (with logins) mirror of it. I have read about EOTK and Onionize but I am not quite sure about it.

Thanks in advance.

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 and Nginx.

Comment: HiddenServices are built to hide the IP address of the service. Therefore creating a hidden service with directly accessing to your web server and database does not seem necessary. I mean, you may use some other mirroring (or even better, caching) services such as CloudFlare.

Comment: Yes, I am already using CloudFlare but the question still stand; what if I want a .onion for my already up and running website as well?

Comment: Actually it is possible to run a tor instance in your main web server and redirect traffic to the web server. But for your question. If your site cannot be accessed from some countries or there are privacy concerns, I suggest using an onion mirror. Otherwise, I do not suggest. But if you want to create a mirror add two lines to the torrc config file.

Comment: HiddenServiceDir THE_DIRECTORY_FOR_PRIVATE_KEY

Comment: HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80 which will redirect the requests of port 80 of your hidden web server to the 127.0.0.1:80 (your nginx address)

Comment: Yes, privacy is the main concern. My port 80 is blank as of the moment, the site running is from another conf file link in /sites-enabled of nginx. Are there any other more security concers if I were to do this?

Comment: Actually you can make the same web server available for both clear and dark net. Or you can run them on two different web servers. I, personally prefer to separate the web servers, so the logs can be separated (Logs of darknet are usually from 127.0.0.1), But both of the web servers will use the same database. You can filter the hidden web server access from outside network, using a firewall. And if you change the port for the darknet website, you should reflect the change in torrc: as an example darknet is in port 8000 -> HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do this. I have tor already running in server (running bitcoind over tor).

Comment: In this post, I've talked about configuring hidden mail service, in which the torrc file is same as hidden web server. Only the ports are different. https://mstajbakhsh.ir/configuring-a-hidden-email-server/